# Ordenar fecha y hora ingresada (Firebase, Javascript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy creando una aplicación web con Firebase y mis conexiones con JS, a la hora de mostrar los datos, se ven de la siguiente manera
:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que no ordena las horas, las fechas si, a lo que quería ver la posibilidad de que se ordene las horas de la más grande a la más pequeña y  de igualmente las fechas, el actual código de ordenamiento que tengo es este:

```
db.collection("citas_registradas").orderBy("fecha", "desc").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
```

Y mis inserts:

```
db.collection("citas_registradas").add({
        nombre: nombre,
        fecha: fecha,
        hora: hora,
        telefono: telefono
    })
```

¿Alguna solución?, agradecería su apoyo :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar que en al ordenar tenga la fecha y hora.

> ```
> db.collection("citas_registradas").orderBy("fecha").orderBy("hora","desc").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
> ```

Comment: No funciona, cuando agrego esa linea de código no despliega ningún dato en la tabla.

Comment: Qué tienes en la linea debajo de esa? Es que lo que pusiste aquí puede que le falte parte del código, sólo sustituye orderBy("fecha", "desc") por orderBy("fecha").orderBy("hora","desc")

Comment: Dejo una respuesta más detallada

Comment: El código ya sustituido lo subí a pastebin para que lo verifiques:
https://pastebin.com/5S8ghyYt

Comment: Eso me parece muy raro, como no soy usuario de firebase leí varias páginas y siempre llegaban al mismo resultado, [aquí](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2577) hay uno de los ejemplos, tiene varias personas que respondieron lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo amigo :)